# how could I get an approach with this Junit testing?

Tags: java, junit

I have some private method. for access the method and do the test I create a new instance as follows in a test class.

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.leopard.spring.StartGame");
    StartGame testSG1 = (StartGame)c.newInstance();

    Method m = testSG1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setUpForm");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(testSG1,null);
```

After doing that I couldn't call for the setUpForm() method to test that. What should I do?

Comment: Do not test private methods. Extract the code into a new class, make it public and test that

Comment: I am not familiar with Junit testing. There is clicklistener in my private method. I just want to test that. is it okay that I create a new class and test them?

Comment: To verify calls on objects used by your unit under test, use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).

Comment: Got that thanks for the help. You just saved me

Comment: Using reflection to test private methods of code produces brittle, pointless tests. Rewrite your code so that it is testable as a first priority not as an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended practice is to test what will be consumed by the consumer. So public methods will be exposed to the consumer so should be tested.